# removing backslash in poorly formed JSON

Tags: json, regex

I am getting JSON from an endpoint written in Perl that looks like this:

```
"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

My question is are those backslashes supposed to be there and if not how do I get rid of them. I'm already replacing all the new line characters but don't know how to replace or remove the backslash.

Comment: Which language does this question pertain to?

Comment: It's much more likely that you're using it wrong rather than the endpoint being wrong (although that is still a possibility). Fixing a JSON string by manually regex-ing it is bad news and is the wrong way of "fixing" this 99% of the time. Does your request have `accept: application/json` on it maybe? Is it being retrieved as text instead of JSON? Where are you seeing the string show up like that?

Comment: Good catch. It was being retrieved as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam's comment is correct. If you still want to remove those  there is no need to do anything. backslashes will just get ignored.Thanks to toto's comment.

```js
let string="{\"key\":\"value\"}";
console.log(string);
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
console.log(string.replace(/\\/g,""));
```

Comment: And what happens when you print `string` **before** the replace? There're no backslashes!

Comment: [Now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: Woah i didnt see that coming @toto